# Stateful session bean, return objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I have a stateful session bean deployed on glassfish, and have a method called `getCars` which returns Collection of objects of `Car` class. Car class is defined in bean project and in client project(actually it is the same class). I have a client(not application client) in which I obtain the reference to bean remote interface as described [here](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB). But my client craches with such exceptions

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA BAD_PARAM 1330446342 Maybe; nested exception is: 
        java.io.NotSerializableException: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: OMG  minor code: 6 completed: Maybe
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.OMGSystemException.notSerializable(OMGSystemException.java:990)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.OMGSystemException.notSerializable(OMGSystemException.java:1005)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ORBUtility.throwNotSerializableForCorba(ORBUtility.java:753)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:765)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputObject.java:709)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAbstractObject(Util.java:501)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:570)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.invokeObjectWriter(IIOPOutputStream.java:760)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:716)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:227)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:268)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:240)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:193)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:932)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:917)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:1044)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:1057)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:774)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:681)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.write(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:394)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.writeResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:490)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:180)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:682)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:216)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1841)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1695)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1078)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:221)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:797)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:561)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2558)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:492)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:528)
```

I think the problem is in marshalling of objects of Car class.  How can resolve this problem with object marshalling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Car` class must implement `java.io.Serializable` so that it can be serialized and transferred 'over the wire'. [Reference: Java serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/)

Also make sure all fields of the `Car` class are of serializable types. For example `Car` may have an `private Engine engine` field. `Engine` must be serializable as well. (or marked with `transient` if it is to be ignored during serialization)

Comment: I've done it serializable but it throws this exception again.

Comment: nope, Car class has 2 attr of int, 1 of String and 1 of java.sql.Date. They all are serializable

Comment: then make sure you have successfully redeployed the new version.

Comment: Uhmm, if my method signature has return type Collection<Car>(Collection isn't serializable), but in method getCars I create ArrayList<Car> and return it. Will it cause such problem?

Comment: all collections is serializable, that's not a problem

Comment: my method also has thrown SqlException, but I've removed it(catch in bean method) and it is still not working

Comment: if everything is serializable and is deployed freshly, it must be working.

Comment: I've done it! The problem was in project's path - it has cyrillic letters, so glassfish didn't want to resolve such path.